# DBT model.yml - use column unique identifiers

Tags: yaml, dbt

I was wondering if there is any possibility to use unique identifiers for columns in dbt models.yml:

```
models:
  - name: my_model
    description: my model description
    columns:
      - unique_identifier_1:
          - name: column_name_1
            description: column description 1
      - unique_identifier_2:
          - name: column_name_2
            description: column description 2
```

My use case is to define (repeating) column definitions and re-use them for multiple models.

What I tried so far (without ids per column):

```
id_columns: &id_columns
  - name: id1
    description: unique identifier for user
    tests:
      - unique
  - name: id2
    description: unique identifier for other thing
    tests:
      - unique

common_columns: &common_columns
  - name: name
    description: Name of User


models:
  - name: my_dbt_model
    description: my description
    columns:
      - <<: *id_columns
      - <<: *common_columns
```

This works but its only including the first ID with its test because the merge `<<:` will only introduce new keys.

Thats why the question came up if I can assign unique keys to each column to overcome this limitation.

I also tested the following but this will create a nested list of objects instead of a list of objects.

```
models:
  - name: my_dbt_model
    description: my description
    columns:
      - <<: *id_columns
      - <<: *common_columns
```

Comment: @jarlh I removed the tag to avoid confusion